# How to solve this combinatorial question with repetitive symbols?

Tags: combinatorics

Question: An alphabet of $40$ symbols is used for transmitting messages in a communication system. How many distinct messages (lists of symbols) of $25$ symbols can the transmitter generate if symbols can be repeated in the message? How many if $10$ of the $40$ symbols can appear only as the first and/or last symbols of the message, the other $30$ symbols can appear anywhere, and repetitions of all symbols are allowed?

Is the answer $(10)^2(30)^{23}$ for the last part of the question? My textbook gave me $(40)^2(30)^{23}$ as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How many if 10 of the 40 symbols can appear only as the first and/or last symbols of the message, the other 30 symbols can appear anywhere, and repetitions of all symbols are allowed?

It is tricky wording; you have to parse it carefully.

It says those 10 can *appear only* in those positions.  That is: only those positions are where they *can* appear; they cannot do so elsewhere.

It does not say *only those* 10 can appear in those positions. That is: it does not prohibit other symbols from appearing there.